# $t$-adic topology (on $\mathbb F_p(1/t)$)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, p-adic-number-theory

Recently I found this interesting [discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3551/algebraically-closed-fields-of-positive-characteristic) about algebraically closed fields of positive characteristic. In the answer marked as the top answer, I read about the $t$-adic topology. The $t$-adic topology is unfamiliar to me and I could not seem to find anything via google.

I do know something about the $p$-adic topology though (cf [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNorm.html) ). So my question is if the $t$-adic topology is defined in the same way as the $p$-adic topology just with a $t$ instead of a prime numbre. I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: The $p$-adics and their topology are a special case of ring completions and the Krull topology. I suspect this is as well, simply by choosing the appropriate ideal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_%28ring_theory%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just the same. You can easily check what the completion of $k(1/t)=k(t)$ is. Best to look first at the $(t)$-adic completion of the ring $k[t]$: this is the ring $k[[t]]$ of formal power series in $t$ over $k$. Then the associated complete ring is $k((t))$, the (finite-tailed) formal Laurent series over $k$. When $k$ is finite, your field is a member of the small but tremendously interesting class of locally compact but not discrete topological fields.

Comment: thank you very much. One thing still confuses me though. You pointed out that $k(1/t)=k(t)$. In [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3551/algebraically-closed-fields-of-positive-characteristic) it says in the top rated answer that $F_p(1/t)$ is "at least analogues to completing $F_p(t)$. Which leads me to assume $F_p(1/t)\neq F_p(t)$

Comment: But of course that’s wrong. Both are gotten by adjoining a single element; and it’s immaterial *in a field* whether you’re adjoining an element or its reciprocal. If they had been talking about the *rings* $k[t]$ and $k[1/t]$, there would be something to say. However, the *ring* $k[1/t]$ can not bear a $(t)$-adic topology, but a $(1/t)$-adic.

Comment: interesting... thank you again. I have a last question. Does this "class of locally compact but not discrete topological fields" have a certain name? And what makes them so interesting? (Maybe you know books/papers I could look into?)

Comment: Sometimes they’re called local fields. Important in number theory and its parallel, the theory of function fields (one variable) over a finite field, via Class Field Theory.